# Recording video in windowed mode games on Java

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, record, video-capture

Is it possible to capture a video stream from a game in windowed mode?
I tried using "FFmpeg" to get only a record of applications not related to Directx or Open GL.

When recording games, a duplicate video stream consisting of black frames is obtained.
[Attempting to record a game Devil May Cry 5 in windowed mode using FFmpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZIWi.png)

Any capture methods related to Java are needed. Since my course project is based on the knowledge of this language. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to record something happening on your screen use OBS https://obsproject.com/ - its free and will directly copy whatever's on your screen, then just use any video editor to reduce anything on the recording you don't want

Comment: It sounds like the OP is looking to do this programmatically, not with some external tool.